# Is it possible to get Visual Studio 2010 Express Web Developer to autoindent it's markup?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, markup, auto-indent

One thing I do like about visual studio is the autoindent feature in the code behind where you can essentially close off the bracket of a loop or method or class and it'll automatically indent everything to make it consistent looking.

Is that possible to do in the markup as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>
- Click `Format Document` in the HTML Source Editing toolbar
- Click `Edit`, `Advanced`, `Format Document`

Comment: oh wow!!! that did it! thanks. although it is Ctrl-K, D. At least on the Express edition

Comment: Hmm, I've always used Ctrl+K, F, and not sure of the corresponding UI option. I'm sure each command may have a slight difference, but any idea what?

Comment: @MrD: It depends on your keyboard settings.  It's the same command.

Comment: It's probably cause I'm on the Express edition, but Ctrl-E,D doesn't do anything for me at all.

Comment: Then is having two keyboard short cuts carry out the same command a consequence of having previous versions installed also, perhaps?

Comment: It depends what settings you chose at launch.

Comment: Excuses my stupidity, but regardless of what I choose at launch, why would it give me two identical routes to a command within the one application?

Comment: @MrD: The keyboard shortcuts change depending on which settings profile you choose at launch. The idea is to make them match older versions of the software (such as Visual Studio 6.0, or Visual Basic 6.0) that you might be more familiar with. Of course, you can change those keybindings at any time, but that's why they are different.

Comment: Sorry, Cody, but that is still far from definitive. Rather just outlines the possibilities. :/ Why would it give me two identical routes to a single command with a default installation, where no short cuts have been altered by the user?